# Using a function with apply Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column within my dataframe that I want to analyze and return a specific value to a new column called "Trade". Data in the column being analyzed looks like this:

```
 QTY 
 (1.00)
1,418,999.89 
 328,536.93 
-100
```

If the value in the quantity column in greater than 0 I want to return "Buy_Code", if not, return "Sell_Code"

I tried to create a function to loop through the dataframe and then use that function within apply but it's not working right. I know there is a ton of info out there on this topic, but I am struggling to grasp how this should be written. Thanks for the help

```
def trade_type():
for index,row in df_loan_tape.iterrows():
    if row['QTY'] > 0:
        df_loan_tape['Trade'] = 'Buy_Code'
    else:
        df_loan_tape['Trade'] = 'Sell_Code'

df_loan_tape['Trade'] = df_loan_tape['QTY'].apply(trade_type)
```

Comment: `df_loan_tape['Trade'] = np.where(df_loan_tape['QTY'] > 0, 'Buy_Code', 'Sell_Code')`. Don't iterate the rows for a simple binary choice, this is vectorized and much faster

Comment: `apply` works row-wise in a Python loop (hence being slower) but without the explicit `for` loop syntax. Here you're `apply`ing a function that _itself_ then iterates through the rows. That's a double iteration of the array.

Comment: Thanks this worked well